# Error when I try to recuperate items from selectManyListbox

Tags: java, jsf-2

I'am using JSF2.0/Primefaces,I have used selectManyListbox that contain elements(projects names),I should recuperate those elements and generate according to the choice another selectManyListbox contain other elments.

First I have tried to fill my first selectManyListbox  and recuperate the choosen items but an error occure :

My JSF:

```
    <h:selectManyListbox size="3"  value="#{TestAjax.selectedProjects} ">
      <f:selectItems value="#{TestAjax.getMyListProject()}" />
     </h:selectManyListbox>
```

My Bean:

```
private List<String> selectedProjects; // + getter + setter
private List<SelectItem> MyListproject;

  public List<SelectItem> getMyListProject()  {
       FindProject fproj =new FindProject();
            if (MyListproject == null) {
            MyListproject = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
            for (String val : fproj.FindListprojects()) { 
         MyListproject.add(new SelectItem(val));
       }
    }
 return MyListproject;
}
```

the error is :

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Target model Type is no a Collection or Array
at     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValuesForModel(MenuRenderer.java:392)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValue(MenuRenderer.java:129)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(MenuRenderer.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1030)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
```

**UPDATE:**
problem Resolved

it was a weard mistake : size="3" should be after the value attribute!

Comment: good you found the problem. close question please.

Comment: What does "recuperate" mean? I saw this question 2 days ago already, but didn't answer because I had no utter idea what you were talking about. Try to use less exotic words so that non-English-natives can also understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDATE: problem Resolved

it was a weard mistake : size="3" should be after the value attribute!

Comment: Cannot reproduce this problem with Mojarra 2.1.1. What JSF impl/version are you using?